# Show HH:mm 24H format in TemplateField using text property

Tags: datetime, date-formatting, templatefield

I'm trying to show a 24 hours format using this line:

```
Text='<%# Bind("Appointment", "{HH:mm}")
```

So how it'll be formated for showing for example 16:40 instead 4:40?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't need to *bind* it, try:

Text='<%# string.Format("{0:HH:mm}", Eval("Appointment"))%>'

otherwise i suppose you can update the field value in the OnDataBound event.

Comment: it still showing like 12 hours format, im want to show in 24h format